# Click a listview item ? how can go other listview?

Tags: android, listview, click

I'm making a learning apk. Its first layout is `fragment_main`, and the second is `second_activity`. The first has a `ListView` showing maths, physics, biology etc. When "maths" is pressed, the first layout should close and go to second layout, and the second layout will show math's subjects.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    String[] myArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Dersler);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aad= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArray);
    setListAdapter(aad);
    }
private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> aad) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}   
}
```

Comment: put your full code here.

Comment: Your activity_main XML file would be helpful as well, and some additional code...

Comment: How can we that ? I did strings it's nice working it's showing lessons but when I click any lesson it have to go exam math_subjects_main